# GoogleApp script. Google calendar script that display current day events

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have some questions regarding google calendar script that I'm building. So I managed to write the script and deploy it as a web app, but I encountered some problems:

1)  It should list all current day events, but it lists only one event of the day
2)  Also I want to display only the title of the event (it’s working now) and the start time and end time of the event. I managed to display a title (events[i].summary) and the start time of the event, but I was unable to display end time of the event and to change the format of the time that it would display time like this for example : 1pm – 2 pm.
3)  Also what I want to do is to make the script run without pressing a button. I want it to work every time I open the published web app or refresh the web app page.

Here is the script code:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('calendarApp');
}


function listEvents() {
var actualDate = new Date();
var endOfDayDate = new      
Date(actualDate.getFullYear(),actualDate.getMonth(),actualDate.getDate(),23,59,59);                                                   
var calendarId = 'primary';
var optionalArgs = {
timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
timeMax: endOfDayDate.toISOString(),
showDeleted: false,
singleEvents: true,
maxResults: 10,
orderBy: 'startTime'
};


var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
var events = response.items;


var allEvents = [];
if (events && events.length > 0) {
for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
allEvents.push(events[i].summary + ' ' + events[i].start.dateTime);
}
return allEvents;
} else {
return ['No events found'];
}
```

And this is a HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calendar App</h1>

<button onclick="listEvents()">List events</button>

<ul id='events'></ul>

<script>
function listEvents() {
 google.script.run
 .withSuccessHandler(function(response){
 var events = response;
 for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
 document.getElementById('events').innerHTML = '<li>' + response[i] + '</li>';
 }
 })
 .withFailureHandler(function(err){
 console.log(err);
 })
 .listEvents();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the link to actual google scritp: [Google Script](https://script.google.com/d/1iRhpIzfOprGVCfpM9tpFS13u55hfn0f8wLnN9Y6R_LwXaSvxJqjJ6I98/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your modified (and working) code. You don't need to use advanced Calendar API since everything you need is available in `CalendarApp`, including a convenient `getEventsForDay()`.
It shows all your events on opening as required.

### code :

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('calendarApp').setTitle('CalendarApp');
}

function listEvents() {
  var today = new Date();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(today);
  var data = [];
  data.push("Events for today "+Utilities.formatDate(today,Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM dd yyyy"));
  if (events && events.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      data.push(events[i].getTitle()+' : '+Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"HH:mm")+' - '+Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getEndTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"HH:mm"))
    }
    return data;
  } else {
    return ['No events found','',''];
  }
}
```

### html & script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:12pt">
    <h2>Calendar App</h2>
    <div id="events">
    </div>
    <script>
    function listEvents() {
     google.script.run
     .withSuccessHandler(function(events){
     document.getElementById('events').innerHTML = document.getElementById('events').innerHTML+'<p>' + events[0] + '</p>';
     for(var i = 1; i < events.length; i++) {
     document.getElementById('events').innerHTML = document.getElementById('events').innerHTML+'<li>' + events[i] + '</li>';
     }
     })
     .withFailureHandler(function(err){
     console.log(err);
     })
     .listEvents();
    };
    window.onload = listEvents();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have slightly modified the interface mainly because I dislike Courrier new. I also added the current date on top of the list. Nice little app ;)

Comment: Thank you for popping up the idea ;)

Comment: if you intend to use this app on a smartphone consider using a meta tag option to increase readability, I use .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1') to the createHtmlOutput call. I works great on an android phone.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build the design for this app now. Nothing fancy (because I'm complete beginner) just trying to make it similar to the google calendar (day view) with all hours listed on the left and the current date on top and a red line which stretches across the table and shows current time. Maybe you have any suggestion where I could start?

Comment: Then the li tag is probably not the best option, I would use a table and probably go to JQuery to make it easier... the design of Google Calendar is somewhat more sofisticated, I wouldn't try to reproduce it. I might find the time to make a proposal in the coming days if you want.

Comment: I see... I would definitely love to see your proposal :)

Comment: Hello @SergeInsas :) I don't want to bother you, but just wanted to ask if you will find time to help me with the calendar?

Comment: not yet, the weather was too sunny this last weekend, didn't feel like to keep busy on my computer... but I keep it in mind.

Comment: Understood :) Thank your for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I use to get my calendar events for the next 5 weeks. And I use it in conjunction with a webapp so it gets returned to a statement that looks like this `document.getElementById('hotbox').innerHTML=hl;` hotbox is just a div.

```
function getMyEvents()
{
  var allCals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var s=Utilities.formatString('<strong>%s</strong>',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d, yyyy HHmm"))
  var min=60 * 1000;
  var hr=60 * min;
  var day=24 * hr;
  var wk=7 * day;
  var start = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0));
  var end=new Date(start.valueOf() + (5 * wk));//you could make this + day instead of + (5 * wk)
  var incl=['Calendar1Name','Calendar2Name'];//These are different calendar names as I have some special calendars for different functions
  for(var i=0;i<allCals.length;i++)
  {
    if(incl.indexOf(allCals[i].getName())>-1)
    {
      s+=Utilities.formatString('<br /><strong>%s</strong>',allCals[i].getName());
      var events=allCals[i].getEvents(start, end);
      if(events)
      {
        s+='<br><ul>';
        for(j=0;j<events.length;j++)
        {
          var calId=allCals[i].getId();
          var evId=events[j].getId();
          if(events[j].isAllDayEvent())
          {
            s+=Utilities.formatString('<li><strong>%s</strong>-%s %s <input type="checkbox" class="markdone" title="Delete Event" name="delevent" value="%s,%s" /></li>', events[j].getTitle(),'All Day',Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d"),calId,evId);
          }
          else
          {
            s+=Utilities.formatString('<li><strong>%s</strong>-%s <input type="checkbox" class="markdone" title="Delete Event" name="delevent" value="%s,%s" /></li>', events[j].getTitle(),Utilities.formatDate(events[j].getStartTime(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"E MMM d, HHmm"),calId,evId);
          }
        }
        s+='</ul>';
      }
    }
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Delete Selected Events" onClick="delSelectedEvents();" style="width:250px;height:35px;text-align:center;margin:10px 0 10px 0;" />';
  //var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'My Events');
  return s;
}
```